# F# Async Task Cancellation without Token

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, f#, task

I am trying to parse hundreds of C source files to map dozens of software signal variables to the names of physical hardware pins. I am trying to do this asynchronously in F#

```
IndirectMappedHWIO
|> Seq.map IndirectMapFromFile  //this is the function with the regex in it
|> Async.Parallel          
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

The issue is that I cannot figure out how to pass in a CancellationToken to end my task. Each task is reading around 300 C files so I want to be able to stop the task's execution as soon as the regex matches. I tried using `Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()` but that does not seem to work. Any ideas on how to pass in a CancellationToken for each task? Or any other way to cancel a task based on a condition?

```
let IndirectMapFromFile pin = 
async {    
    let innerFunc filename = 
        use streamReader = new StreamReader (filePath + filename)
        while not streamReader.EndOfStream do
            try
                let line1 = streamReader.ReadLine()
                streamReader.ReadLine() |> ignore
                let line2 = streamReader.ReadLine()

                if(obj.ReferenceEquals(line2, null)) then
                    Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()  //DOES NOT WORK!!
                else    
                    let m1 = Regex.Match(line1, @"^.*((Get|Put)\w+).*$");
                    let m2 = Regex.Match(line2, @"\s*return\s*\((\s*" + pin.Name + "\s*)\);");
                    if (m1.Success && m2.Success) then
                        pin.VariableName <- m1.Groups.[1].Value
                        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort() //DOES NOT WORK!!
                    else
                        ()
            with
            | ex -> ()
        ()

    Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "Rte*") //all C source and header files that start with Rte
    |> Array.iter innerFunc
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to stop *all* the tasks when any one of them finds a match? Or are you wanting to exit from the Array.iter when that pin is successfully matched?

Comment: Have you had any luck using the overload of `Async.RunSynchronously` that takes a `CancellationToken`?

Comment: Each task is independent of each other , they are trying to match unique regex. So if one task gets a match it should cancel only itself. The other tasks should keep working until they find their own regex match.

Answer (score 2):

Asyncs cancel on designated operations, such as on `return!`, `let!`, or `do!`; they don't just kill the thread in any unknown state, which is not generally safe. If you want your asyncs to stop, they could for example:

- be recursive and iterate via `return!`. The caller would provide a `CancellationToken` to `Async.RunSynchronously` and catch the resulting `OperationCanceledException` when the job is done.
- check some thread-safe state and decide to stop depending on it.

Note that those are effectively the same thing: the workers who iterate over the data check what is going on and cancel *in an orderly fashion*. In other words, it is clear when exactly they check for cancellation.

**Using async cancellation** might result in something like this:

```
let canceler = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource()
let rec worker myParameters =
    async {
        // do stuff
        if amIDone() then canceler.Cancel()
        else return! worker (...) }

let workers = (...) |> Async.Parallel

try Async.RunSynchronously(workers, -1, canceler.Token) |> ignore
with :? System.OperationCanceledException -> ()
```

**Stopping from common state** could look like this:

```
let keepGoing = ref true
let rec worker myParameters =
    if !keepGoing then
        // do stuff
        if amIDone() then keepGoing := false
        worker (...)

let makeWorker initParams = async { worker initParams }
// make workers
workers |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore
```

If the exact timing of cancellation is relevant, I believe the second method may not be safe, as there may be a delay until other threads see the variable change. This doesn't seem to matter here though.